# Imaginary part of the world behind the event horizon

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics

Outside the event horizon of a black hole, quantum field theory and General Relativity are completely sufficient for understanding the physics of what occurs; that is what Hawking radiation is. But even the combination of those two leads to an information paradox that has not yet been resolved.

If we assume that [Estakhr's hypothesis of complex universe](http://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/DNP17/Event/304489) is correct and there is an imaginary part inside the event horizon that we can not perceive it.

What would be the impact of the theory of complex world on the black hole [information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox)?

What if the information flow from the real part of the world (outside the event horizon of a black hole) to its imaginary part (inside the event horizon of a black hole)?

What does it mean philosophically, if this happens for information?

Comment: The universe has dealt us a wildcard. There is a portion of it that we can never fully comprehend, because we are unable to perceive it. It possesses a power which we can never hope to harness. How mysterious and marvelous! And possibly beneficial for our own good and well-being. Perhaps it is the heart, mind and soul of the universe; and unknowable. We can only perceive its effects? Like animal tracks in freshly fallen snow?

Comment: Actually, quantum field theory and General Relativity don't fully agree.  There have been theories of quantum gravity, but it's real hard to observe quantum effects and gravitational effects in the same body.